# What is srgb bt.709?

Tags: python, color-management

I am the author of an add-on for Blender 2.8.

I have one user that is experiencing an error. I understand what is causing it, but I don't understand why.

My add-on is selecting the "Standard" option from this list:

[image]

The user, however, does not have that option. Hist list looks like this (note also the different Display Device):

[image]

We are both using clean installs of the latest Blender 2.8 beta (11 July 2019 build).

What exactly is "sRGB / BT.709"? Why does he have this option, whereas I do not?

Comment: He might either have replaced his color management configuration entirely when installing filmic, or has the OCIO environment variable set. See Leanders link for further reference.

Comment: Where is that one from? In my configuration, the display type is clearly listed as sRGB. BT.709 when listed as a display type, would be conflicting with the “sRGB” label, hence it seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

BT.709 is an **HDTV** color standard, hence different options list. The user mentioned may use such a device. It'd be good if his device had a VGA input either. See [color.org](http://www.color.org/chardata/rgb/BT709.xalter) site for more info on the subject.